# How to handle web sockets (Socket IO) errors in a web app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sockets, socket.io, mern

I'm building a MERN web app that uses web sockets communication between server and client. Few times I have faced an issue when web sockets error actually crashed the app because I have no error handling.

[image]

I know that I need to handle these errors somehow. But couldn't find any info about this on the web. 
The question is: 
**Should I inform the user about sockets errors if sockets are not the main functionality of the app, it is not a chat app. Sockets are the only improvement to collaboration between users.??**

Should I show users some message about sockets problems? Or should I handle them by some noOp function and try to reconnect sockets??